# I want to move selected tabelview cell on top

Tags: swift, uitableview

i am trying to move tableview selected cell on top

```
    let itemToMove = arrInrestLocation[indexPath.row]
    arrInrestLocation.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    arrInrestLocation.append(itemToMove)
    let destinationindexPath = NSIndexPath(row: arrInrestLocation.count - 1, section: indexPath.section)
    tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: destinationindexPath as IndexPath)
```

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are moving the row and the item to the bottom not to the top. You just need to edit your code a bit. The first row of a table's section is row zero. The append method adds the item to the end of the array, you need to insert it at the front of the array instead.

```
 let itemToMove = arrInrestLocation[indexPath.row]
 arrInrestLocation.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 arrInrestLocation.insert(itemToMove, at: 0) //move to front of array
 let destinationindexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section) 
 tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: destinationindexPath as IndexPath)
```

Comment: Your welcome, if it helped please accept the answer.

Comment: i have to this on a tap of button in controller